# TortoiseSVN Commit Failed - Windows 7 64bit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

kinda having a big problem here:
I've mounted a networkdrive to Z:\ there are some SVN repositories stored on that drive. 
(Created with TortoiseSVN -> RightMouseButton -> TortoiseSVN -> Create Repository here).

Everthing worked fine until now. I wanted to commit a change and got the following error message:

> Commit failed (details follow):
>   Can't close file
>   'Z:\SVN\Software\Plugins\Imaging\Test\db\transactions\0-f.txn\changes':
>   Zugriff verweigert (It's german for: access denied)

I do have full access to that folder! Even if I log in as local or domain administrator I keep getting this error message.

Here is what I tried:

- Shutting down security software (Kaspersky)
- Creating a new repository
- Checking access to that folder (I can create/change and delete files)
- Cleaning the repository

Any suggestions why on earth I keep getting that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to store repositories on a network share and access them using the file:// protocol: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share

If you need to access the repositories over the network it's worth setting up the server for access via the svn://, svn+ssh:// or http:// protocols - there's details on how linked from the page I mention above, or the svn book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: Right now I cannot change the way the repositories are handled. It's just a strange behavior since every other PC is able to commit any changes.

Comment: Trouble is there's a lot that could be going wrong and it's very hard to track down (hence why it's not recommended). If the repositories are hosted on a Linux machine you could probably use the svn+ssh protocol without having to make any significant changes, provided you have a user account on that machine?

Comment: unfortunately they are stored on a windows server machine. I did a complete reinstallation of the working machine with the result that it's working now. We might start setting up a svn server since we dont want that kind of trouble! Thanks for your reply.